# Stop caching of single tile in Apache Tiles and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, apache-tiles

I am having a problem with caching of tiles while using Spring MVC and Apache Tiles.

I have a admin page, with many users. The login works perfectly and the content users generate is mapped to the correct user, but when users are logged in, they get each others content! (e.g. the username in the top switches between all users, so you see other users username).

Users are logged in with Spring Security.

I have tried to figure out how to turn of caching of tiles, because I think it might be something related to Apache Tiles and not Spring MVC.

All suggestions for solutions are very welcome.

EDIT:

Menu tile:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="${param.currentView eq 'index' ? 'active' : ''}"><a href="/apps/blogs/">My articles</a></li>
        <li class="${param.currentView eq 'article' ? 'active' : ''}"><a href="/apps/blogs/new">New article</a></li>
        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
            <li class="dropdown" class="${param.currentView eq 'admin' ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/apps/blogs/admin/">Users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </sec:authorize>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><sec:authentication
                    property="principal.firstName"/>&nbsp;<sec:authentication
                    property="principal.lastName"/><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/apps/blogs/changePassword">Change password</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</sec:authorize>
```

BlogsController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = "application/json")
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public class BlogsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = "text/html")
    public String index(Model model, Authentication auth, @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1") Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "showDeletedOnly", defaultValue = "false") boolean showDeletedOnly, @RequestParam(value = "sectionId", defaultValue = "-1") int sectionId, @RequestParam(value = "username", defaultValue = "") String username) {

        double resultsPrPage = 10.0; // Double type is used, to calculate the last page using Math.ceil.

        BlogUser userDetails = (BlogUser) auth.getPrincipal();

    // CODE RETRIEVING THE BLOG ENTRIES....

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Tiles configuration:

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
              value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/blogs/shared/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: It seems you are mixing stateless and statefull beans the wrong way. Please post some of your code, where the usernames are displayed, the controller and the tile config.

Comment: Stefan: I have updated the question. do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: this has nothing to do with tiles.

Comment: mck: ok, what could be the issue then? Because it has something to do with something.